# what's the difference and affect of set[sync-log=false]for tidb

Tags: mysql, tidb

In tidb ,when open `sync-log` ,disk io util can be over `90%`,after `set sync-log=false`,it goes down to `1%`,what's the bad effect of this config?

Answer (score 0):

In short, `sync-log=true` keeps data safe, but hurts performance.

TiDB is based on the Raft consensus algorithm, it needs to make sure every
raft log is persisted to the majority's disk before committing them. To make
sure a log is persisted, we need two steps:

1. write(log_fd, log)
2. fsync(log_fd)

When `sync-log=false`, TiDB skips `fsync`, it helps performance and is safe if
there is no power failure. Set it to true, your data is always intact even if
there is a power failure.

See more: https://pingcap.com/docs/v3.0/faq/tidb/